# how to use keyboard buttons in making code

Tags: vb.net

i want to make a code such that

`pressing w button ; label1.text="u pressed w"`

```
pressing thd down arrow ; label1.text="u pressed down arow"
```

i tried usin case but nothing happened

```
Private Sub frmMain_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.W
            MessageBox.Show("Move forward")
        Case Keys.A
            MessageBox.Show("Move left")
        Case Keys.S
            MessageBox.Show("Move back")
        Case Keys.D
            MessageBox.Show("Move right")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: In design mode, go to te properties of your form, and set `KeyPreview` to `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change...

```
Select Case e.KeyCode
```

to...

```
Select Case e.KeyValue
```

And it should work.

Comment: there is an error says                                                                                                   'value' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs'.

Comment: Did you type `e.KeyValue` or just e.Value, needs to be `e.KeyValue`.